# Linebreak issue in Pine Script Editor, when I paste code

Tags: pine-script, line-breaks, tradingview-api

If i paste a few line of pine script code from my windows machine into the editor
I do get always some line break issues

ie

```
 line.new(timestamp('2022-12-08 05:21:00.210') , 22.67, timestamp('2022-12-09 05:21:00.210'), 22.67, extend=extend.none, color=color.red, width=2, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
  box.new(timestamp('2022-12-07 05:21:00.210'),22.9232459016393,timestamp('2022-12-08 05:21:00.210'),23.1062295081966,color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 90),1,line.style_solid,extend.none,xloc.bar_time,color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 96),"short-07.12.2022 05:21:00")
  box.new(timestamp('2022-12-07 05:21:00.210'),22.9232459016393,timestamp('2022-12-08 05:21:00.210'),23.1062295081966,color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 90),1,line.style_solid,extend.none,xloc.bar_time,color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 96),"short")
```

Does anybody solved this issue before.. do I need a special character at the end of the line?

I try to copy a few generated lines to the pine scripts editor

Comment: the error is:  Mismatched input 'box.new' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the error because your line 2 and 3 have space and tab before them.
Please align your line like :

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
line.new(timestamp('2022-12-08 05:21:00.210') , 22.67, timestamp('2022-12-09 05:21:00.210'), 22.67, extend=extend.none, color=color.red, width=2, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
box.new(timestamp('2022-12-07 05:21:00.210'),22.9232459016393,timestamp('2022-12-08 05:21:00.210'),23.1062295081966,color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 90),1,line.style_solid,extend.none,xloc.bar_time,color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 96),"short-07.12.2022 05:21:00")
box.new(timestamp('2022-12-07 05:21:00.210'),22.9232459016393,timestamp('2022-12-08 05:21:00.210'),23.1062295081966,color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 90),1,line.style_solid,extend.none,xloc.bar_time,color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 96),"short")
```

This code works.